# Mailing list software with easy to use GUI

Tags: software-recommendation, email

I'm looking for an easy to use making list program so, I can use my existing email to send to all the people on my list.
I want to have it so I can send it with out them seeing each 
others email addresses and so I can have 
there names in the email, like a personalize emails
 you get when you sign up for stuff.

Also I would like for it to have a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it (although I intend to try it out soon), but the [Mail Merge Thunderbird extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/) looks like it will do what you need. From the description:

> If you send an e-mail to multiple recipients, there are three problems: First you are often not allowed to send one e-mail to more than 25 or 100 recipients at the same time. Second you don't want each recipient to see the other recipients. Third you can't personalize the e-mail. Mail Merge solves these problems!

Answer (score 3):

GNU Mailman is the most popular. I looked at other mailing list software like phplist and dadamail as well. Here's my findings when I tested them a year ago:

**GNU Mailman**

- written in Python
- very widely used (Sourceforge, Ubuntu, Debian, and many other large scale installations in the wild)
- does not require a database
- primitive web ui but reliable
- package provided by just about every distribution, very easy to install
- very reliable bounce detection
- I still cannot create list from webui and must be done via shell. but all other admin tasks work fine for me
- I had to write a custom script to export subscriber lists for backup

**phplist**

- written in php
- nice web interface
- pretty easy to install
- pretty popular, many distribution provide packages
- requires mysql database
- I was alarmed by many reports of insecurity

**dadamail**

- written in perl (CGI)
- requires mysql database
- I never tested it as installation was difficult

I ended up with **GNU Mailman** and am very happy with it.